# Unable to print a panel in c# windows application

Tags: c#-4.0, windows

Hi i am printing a panel in my windows application. when i click the print panel it is opening the print dialog after i **click print** in the print dailog it **is throwing an exception.**

```
System.CompoentModel.Win32Exception{"Access is denied"}
```

Here is the code which i am using.

```
Bitmap MemoryImage;

    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.BackColor = Color.White;
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;

        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle pagearea = e.PageBounds;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, (panel1.Width / 2) - (this.panel1.Width / 2), this.panel1.Location.Y);

    }
```

Please let me know how to solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting this in both windows xp as well as windows 7?
May be user access control problem

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your code, it is a configuration problem on your machine.  Try another printer to localize the problem and ask your LAN administrator or IT staff for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Bitmap MemoryImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            Rectangle pagearea = e.PageBounds;
            panel1.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, panel1.ClientRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(MemoryImage, (pagearea.Width / 2) - (this.panel1.Width / 2), this.panel1.Location.Y);
        }
```